# Using deferred to chain loops with multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

There are multiple questions that already have an answer about this, but all aren't working so far it this kind of setup.

```
function login(u,p) {
   console.log(1);
   return $.post(url, {u,p});
}

function out() {
   console.log(3);
   //a function that does not return deferred
   // clear cookies
}

function doSomething() {
  console.log(2);
  // a function that returns a deferred
  return $.post(...);
}
var data = [{u: 'au', p: 'ap'}, {u: 'bu', p: 'bp'}]

$.each(data, function(k,v){
  login(v.u, v.p).then(doSomething).then(out);
});
```

I was expecting it's sequence to be like:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

But I get

```
1
2
1
3
2
3
```

Why is it like that, even though I am waiting for the promise to be resolve using `then`

Comment: `$.each(data, function(k,v){` is not waiting on a promise for its next iteration.

Comment: then how do I make that wait.

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct approach is, but I would try using a recursive function that calls itself at the end of the chain `.then(theFunction(data));` and just shifts an element off array `data` each time until there are none left.

Comment: i think that is what I did the last time, i'll try

Comment: Depending on how long the AJAX calls take, they might not return in the same order they were fired off in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create a recursive function like @Popnoodles have mentioned.

e.g.

```
function a() {
  return $.post();
}

function b() {
  return $.post();
}

function c() {
   console.log('no promise.');
}

// and the recursive main function

function main() {
   if(counter < data.length){
      $.when(a().then(b).then(c)).done(function(){
        counter++;
        main();
      });
   }
}

main();
```

[Here is how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/DBbmF/), open the console to see how it logs the function in sequence.

Comment: Is it possible to do this and also pass a value that a would return to b? Or I would I need to use global variables for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the logins to run synchronously:

```
var p = new jQuery.Deferred();
$.each(data, function(k,v){
  p.then(function() {
    return login(v.u, v.p);
  }).then(doSomething).then(out);
});
```

Each new item iterated over in `$.each` won't trigger a new response until `p` finishes the last one.