# Chain multiple AJAX calls with delay and passing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm working on a way to chain a set of 3 ajax calls per variable against an array of data with some delay in between.

Taking into account [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22824015/1422679)

I'm trying to update the code to achieve the following:

1. Add a delay in the b() and c() function
2. Pass a variable from a() to b() and from b() to c()

Is there a way I can pass a variable a() would generate to b() *without* using global variables? If not that's fine, I'd just like to know.

And how exactly can I get b() to be delayed for several seconds before processing c()? I would assume adding in a `setTimeout` would work as it's waiting for the promise before it starts c(), but this is not the case.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBbmF/3/)

```
function a(user, pass) {
  return $.post('/echo/json/', {}, function(re){
    console.log(1);
  });
}

function b() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    return $.post('/echo/json/', {}, function(re){
        console.log(2);
    });
  }, 3000);
}

function c() {
  console.log(3);
}

var data = [{u: 'au', p: 'ap'}, {u: 'bu', p: 'bp'}];

var counter = 0;

function main() {
  if(counter < data.length) {
    $.when(a(data[counter].u, data[counter].p).then(b).then(c)).done(function(){
      counter++;
      main();
    })
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Do you want to delay the requests until `a()` has responded (and the same for `c()` before `b()` responds? Or do you want to just want to execute base on a delay, regardless of success, failure or even completion.

Comment: for one, function b returns undefined

Comment: @JaromandaX function b returns a promise

Comment: @Matt I want to delay b() until a() has been completed, and then add a 3 second delay before it starts execution of b().

Comment: Assuming that you want to wait, you should be calling be within a callback like so, `.then(res => { b(res).then(r => { c(r).then(finally => { // Everything complete }); });

Comment: @Matt - no it doesn't - there's no `return` from function b, therefore the returned value is `undefined`

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't know what you mean, the jsfiddle shows no errors and works as expected.

Comment: console.log(b()) ... `undefined` .. the fact that `3` is logged immediately after `1` should be a red flag warning that it's **not** working right

Comment: @JaromandaX but if you wait 3 seconds b does get logged after everything else

Comment: Yes. That does not mean b has returned a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh right. I don't understand how I can delay without wrapping it in a `setTimeout` but that seems to stop the promise from coming through

Comment: b() returns undefined because Javascript is NOT a blocking language...meaning that the `setTimeout` function is just passed over regardless the delay. You are just registering some code to be executed after the time out, but the end of the function ( the closing `}` ) is hit long before the `b()` function is called. This results in a `void` or `undefined` response from the original call. You can wrap the `b()` in a custom built promise to have `c()` wait on the `setTimeout()`

Comment: You can't delay without a settimeout

Comment: @Matt thanks Matt, I'm intrigued, are you able to expand on building a custom promise to have `c()` wait on `setTimeout` or can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Matt thanks a lot, this working how I want it now. http://jsfiddle.net/DBbmF/5/

Comment: @Matt if it solved your problem, can you please accept as the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that `c()` isn't executed until after the timeout code has been called, create your own promise and return it from the `b()` function. You should wrap the `setTimeout` function in this promise, and call the `resolve(res)` method to notify the `.then()` functions watching the promise, passing an object representing the `data` or `body` of the response.

```
function b(dataFromA) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      return $.post('/echo/json/', {}, res => {
        let dataToB = res;
        console.log(2);
        resolve(dataToB);
      });
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

Note that `b()` now accepts data that can be passed from the response of the `a()` promise. You can manipulate this data inside the `b(res)` function or in the `promiseFromA.then(res => { // ... Your promise callback code });` before calling `b(res)`.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout as used in function b is not a promise. i will find some docs to site and post shortly but here is what i see.

to use a promise you need to call a promise method, setTimeout is not a promise. it is only a delay. it has to do with the event loop in javascript or in the javascript runtime to be more correct. there is some good stuff over here --> https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/async%20%26%20performance

also .then only works to resolve a promise

getify really breaks it down but i would start with the javascript event loop

Comment: @EdKwong This is not really an answer. You should provide a solution. This would make a great comment though

Comment: Noted it wouldnt let me comment above i was just trying to help

Comment: You have to earn 10 points of reputation before you can comment. Just takes one vote :) Keep active